# Can't see Moderator tools/flag indicator

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I might have missed an update by the Stack Overflow team, but flag indicator (moderator tools) has been missing from my account since the past 2 days.

[image]

Currently I am moderating old questions directly from [New answers to old Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions), but yes I am able to flag so I am sure there isn't any specific restrictions placed on me.

I even thought it might be caused by my browser history but I cleared it more than 5 times on both my laptops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 10k flag queue is gone: [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue/228861#228861)

The reason for removing the flag queue was because of its ineffectiveness, clumsy interface and lack of use. Changes to the Low Quality Posts queue (such as NAA flags adding a review to the queue) fulfil the original purpose of the 10k flag queue.

You can still access other parts of the 10k tools by clicking Review -> Tools, or by going directly to https://stackoverflow.com/tools.

Comment: yeah that's the same way I am accessing tools. Thanks for the update. I just came to know **http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged is no more exist**.